# Unicode in vimrc no longer displaying correctly

Tags: vimrc, unicode

I'm using VIM 8.1.2234 with `+multi_byte` and `+multi_lang`

In my `vimrc` file, I have `set listchars=tab:▸\ ,trail:·` (Notice the "▸" and the "·")

When I `cat` or `less` my vimrc, the text displays as [intuitively] expected.
When I *use* vim, the options behave as [intuitively] expected.
However, when I *edit* my vimrc, I see `set listchars=tab:â<96>¸\ ,trail:Â·`

This has not always been the case. I have not changed my VIM version but I have tweaked my vimrc a bit. I'm convinced it is a setting I tweaked but for the life of me, I cannot figure out which. I tried backing out changes, but no luck.

FWIW, I got both the "▸" and the "·" characters into my vimrc via direct keyboard entry.

I don't know if it matters, but now when I open my vimrc file, I get a `[converted]` flag on the status line. (My encoding is and has always been `set encoding=utf-8`)

## Update

I ran `:verbose set fileencoding?` and got `fileencoding=latin1` (despite my setting it to UTF-8) When I ran `:verbose set fileencodings?`, VIM reports `fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,default,latin1` I tried `:e ++enc=utf8 ~/.vimrc` and got `[ILLEGAL BYTE in line 213]` on the status line. Line 213 is defines a macro I use for massaging specific PHP arrays into a Lua tables. Once I removed this macro line -- commenting out was not enough -- my `listchars` definitions appeared correctly [while editing] and the `[converted]` status tag went away.

I examined the macro definition closely (with a hex editor, as suggested) and it confirmed that all whitespace was actually whitepsace and all "normal characters" where just that, normal. I suspect that the format of the macro is confusing VIM's parser.

It was VIM's automatic encoding change from UTF-8 to Latin1 that broke `listchars`. VIM, for whatever reason, gets confused by my macro definition; this is what forces VIM to change the encoding. There is no deep understanding or solution here; the issue has been cleared but the problem remains unsolved.

FWIW, here's the macro definition that [now, but didn't always] breaks VIM's parsing:

`let @z = "^M^MV-%->O    $data = [^[-%O▸ ];^M    $persist( $data, \"\" );^[^M%-$F/ v$kby^M%-f\"p^M%^M^Mma-$%-mb'aV'b:s/{/[/g^M'aV'b:s/}/]/g^M'aV'b:s/: / => /g^M"`

Comment: How about `:verbose set fileencoding?` when you have your vimrc open? Do you have "utf-8" listed in `:verbose set fileencodings?` (note it's plural here.) Does it work if you open the file with `:e ++enc=utf-8 ~/.vimrc`?

Comment: When I run `:verbose set fileencoding?` i get `fileencoding=latin1` (despite my setting it to UTF-8) When I run `:verbose set fileencodings?` it reports `fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,default,latin1` Also, when I use `:e ++enc-`... I get this: `[ILLEGAL BYTE in line 213]` -- that line defines a macro that I use for massaging a PHP assoc array into a Lua table.

Comment: That illegal byte is then probably why it's not recognizing it as UTF-8... Maybe drop that line and see what happens? Or consider using an hex editor to see which byte might be the problematic one...

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include more details.

Comment: I removed line 213. (Commenting it out was insufficient.) The issue went away. The only "offensive" character in the macro was a ^M; everything else is plain, printable text or whitespace. How is an "illegal byte" defined? Regarding adding "more details:" The situation has been resolved without knowing the underlying issue, so short of posting my entire `.vimrc`, I'm not sure what else I can add. What do you suggest?

Comment: So removing line 213 solved the issue right? Make sure all characters in the line were *really* only whitespace and printable characters... Maybe save that line only to a separate file and use something like `xxd` on it (or perhaps `cat -v`) to see if it had any weird characters? Yeah if you post your vimrc somewhere (a pastebin or github gist) I'd be happy to help you further with that.

Comment: Regarding [edit]ing the question: right now a lot of the useful information (like the `[converted]` message and result of `:set` queries) is in comments only. It should be in the question, so that others reading the question and planning to write an answer could easily find all relevant information. Also for the future, when others with the same problem bump into this question after encountering a similar issue. Finding all context easily is very important!

Comment: Does removing the ▸ from line 213 fix the issue? Does deleting the entire contents of the string (the rhs of the Vimscript assignment) fix it? If so, can you narrow down which part of the string is causing the issue?

Comment: @Rich I think the ▸ is what his listchars is doing to a tab character... LiamF any chance you could upload the problematic file to a service that would preserve it exactly, such as a Git repository or perhaps a paste bin that you can upload using a command-line tool? Or perhaps post the xxd output for that particular line? Something like `sed -n 213p problem_vimrc.txt | xxd` might be able to capture that...

Comment: @filbranden Ah, of course. I was wondering what it was doing in there.